# Teamcity not recognizing multiple tags using cypress cli

Tags: cypress, teamcity

I am using Cypress 12.8.1 and using TeamCity Enterprise 2019.1 (cannot upgrade)

I want to specify which tags to run in a build step.  It was working fine using a single tag, but now we need to do tags="@tag1 and not @tag2".  This runs perfectly on cmd and powershell terminal.  But, when I put it into a TeamCity build step, it ignores the second condition of the tag and runs all @tag1 even if there's @tag2.

I've tried different things and nothing works:

- escaping the quotes in different ways
- trying single vs double quotes
- reordering the items in --env setting of the cypress command
- using a parameter/variable as the tag value

Example of one that works on terminal or cmd dialog, but not in TC

`npx cypress run --e2e --browser chrome --env TAGS="@tag1 and not @tag2",allure=true`

Comment: Workaround - use a script, shell, or bash and then call it via TeamCity. But that will be committed to a repo. "" should have worked fine in the case. I do not see a reason of why TeamCity should not.

Comment: Thanks for the response @KumarRishabh - We tried that (sorry I forgot to add it) and it still didn't work.  We don't see a reason either which is why I'm looking for help with it.

Comment: there is nothing wrong you are doing. Can you try reaching out to the TeamCity support team on this? Not sure what the issue is.